Problem with duplicate anonymous user accounts in parse-server
I have 6 flutter applications running on 1 parse server (these applications are copies of each other, they use one package but represent different cities London, Paris etc. I have implemented the anonymous accounts function and I have a problem. Assuming that 1 user would now download all 6 cities and select the anonymous user option in each city it will create 6 anonymous accounts, and the User class contains deviceId1-6 columns responsible for storing the id of the device on which he logged in and I see that they are the same. I will mention that when the user has already created an account and on other cities he logs in to it, whether with login and password - or with fb/google/apple then the problem does not occur. I realize that I could delete these anonymous users after some time, but in case such a user gains some progress in several cities, I would like him to be able to assign it all to one account, is there any way to do that? This makes analytical work very difficult.
